# Longest matching suffix while using aggregate functions

Tags: postgresql, xml, aggregate, limits

## Background

Looking to find the longest matching string suffix.

## Setup

Consider the following [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d395f/4):

```
CREATE TABLE noun
    ("label" varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO noun
    ("label")
VALUES
    ('bar'),
    ('blue bar'),
    ('red bar'),
    ('green bar'),
    ('purple bar'),
    ('handlebar')
;

CREATE TABLE noun_inflection
    ("label_singular" varchar(9), "label_plural" varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO noun_inflection
    ("label_singular", "label_plural")
VALUES
    ('bar', 'bars'),
    ('handlebar', 'handlebar')
;
```

And the following query:

```
select * from noun n, noun_inflection ni
where
  n.label = 'handlebar' and
  n.label ilike '%'||ni.label_singular;
```

This returns two rows:

```
LABEL       | LABEL_SINGULAR | LABEL_PLURAL
------------+----------------+-------------
handlebar   | bar            | bars
handlebar   | handlebar      | handlebar
```

The first row is correct, but not desired. For this particular purpose, the Levenshtein distance can be used to eliminate the duplicate:

```
select * from noun n, noun_inflection ni
where
  n.label = 'handlebar' and
  n.label ilike '%'||ni.label_singular
order by
  levenshtein( n.label, ni.label_singular )
limit 1;
```

This re-orders the rows based on the label similarity. In this example, "handlebar" exactly matches "handlebar", and has a distance of 0. Adding the `limit 1` restricts the query to a single row.

## Problem

The setup works, except PostgreSQL 9.1 [does not respect](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/A737B7A37273E048B164557ADEF4A58B17C60299@ntex2010i.host.magwien.gv.at) LIMIT modifiers in aggregate functions. That is, the following doesn't work:

```
SELECT
  xmlagg( xmlement( ... ) ORDER BY levenshtein( ... ) LIMIT 1 )
FROM
  noun n, noun_inflection ni
```

The problem remains. The word `'handlebar'` matches `'%bar'` and `'%handlebar'`, and so this returns two rows, which, in turn, injects two xmlelements into the resulting XML document when only one is expected.

## Update #1

To clarify:

```
select
  xmlagg(
    xmlelement(
      name "noun",
      trim( TRAILING label_singular FROM n.label ) || ni.label_plural
    )
  )
from
  noun n, noun_inflection ni
where
  n.label = 'handlebar' and
  n.label ilike '%'||ni.label_singular;
```

That should return a single 'handlebar' XML element. Currently, it returns 'handlebars' and 'handlebar':

```
{ "Value": "<noun>handlebars</noun><noun>handlebar</noun>", "Type": "xml" }
```

The desired output is:

```
{ "Value": "<noun>handlebar</noun>", "Type": "xml" }
```

## Update #2

Even though the [following code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d395f/25) solves the handlebar/handlebars problem, it prevents multiple *different* nouns from being returned:

```
select
  xmlagg(
    xmlelement(
      name "noun",
      trim( TRAILING label_singular FROM n.label ) || ni.label_plural
    )
  )
from
  noun n, noun_inflection ni
where
  n.label = 'handlebar' and
  n.label ilike '%'||ni.label_singular
group by n.label, ni.label_singular
order by levenshtein( n.label, ni.label_singular )
limit 1
```

## Update #3

This looks like it will require a stored function. Something along the lines of:

```
  SELECT
    trim( TRAILING label_singular FROM p_noun ) || ni.label_plural
  FROM
    noun_inflection ni
  WHERE
    p_noun ILIKE '%'||ni.label_singular
  ORDER BY
    levenshtein( p_noun, ni.label_singular )
  LIMIT 1;
```

## Question

How would you match and return only the longest substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only viable solution I could find was to write a function:

```
  FUNCTION get_noun_inflection( p_noun text, ... params ... )
  -- ... body, declare, variable, etc. 
  SELECT
    CASE
      -- ... conditions ...
      THEN trim( TRAILING ni.label_singular FROM p_noun ) || ni.label_plural
      -- Noun in singular form (no pluralization)
      ELSE p_noun
    END
  FROM
    noun_inflection ni
  INTO
    v_result
  WHERE
    p_noun ILIKE '%'||ni.label_singular
  ORDER BY
    levenshtein( p_noun, ni.label_singular )
  LIMIT 1;

  IF NOT found THEN
    v_result := p_noun;
  END IF;

  RETURN v_result;

  -- ... exception handling, default values, cost, etc.
```

Then use the function:

```
select
  xmlagg(
    xmlelement(
      name "noun",
      get_noun_inflection( n.label )
    )
  )
from
  noun n
```

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with the (maybe too obvious?):

```
select * from noun n, noun_inflection ni
where
  n.label = 'handlebar' and
  n.label ilike '%'||ni.label_singular
order by
  char_length(ni.label_singular) DESC
limit 1;
```

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.1 does not respect LIMIT modifiers in aggregate functions.

Comment: But you are not aggregating here, you are joining

Comment: DaveJarvis it is not at all clear how this answer does not address your problem. Why the arbitrary restriction of not using `LIMIT`?

Comment: Can't you use a cte or a derived table, like this?: `SELECT xmlagg(...) FROM (query by Thomas) AS t;`

Comment: You could add a windows function with row_number() if that syntax works better for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the longest substring that means there is no other which is longer.  A `NOT EXISTS` predicate will give this.

```
select
    <whatever>
from <your table> as aa
where <predicates>
and not exists
    (
    select 1
    from <your table> as bb
    where <predicates>
    and len(bb.SomeColumn) > len(aa.SomeColumn)
    );
```

Of course the `len()` function can be replaced by `levenshtein()` as your examples show.  The correlated query may cause performance issues.  Is your set of probe values sufficiently small to pre-compute the function values for each?

You may be able to use one of the fast-but-wrong queries to reduce the initial sets to a managably small superset of the correct answer(s), which can then be processed by a slow-but-correct algoithm.